# disable outside click if popup is open

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

I am using bootstrap, My scenario is as follows:

There is a button, on clicking button I am opening up a popup and in that popup there is a button that is again opening up a new popup. Now I am trying to disable outside click when my popups are open. However when first popup is open then I have already disabled the outside click, but when it is not happening for 2nd popup.

I have used these attributes on button:

```
 <button type="button" name="delete" class="btnbmbm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-user-confirm" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">Delete Me </button>
```

And here is complete html file:

```
<div class="page account-page customer-info-page customer-delete-info">

    <div class="page-body">

        <div class="form-fields">
            <input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.CustomerId" id="customerId" />
            <div class="del-section">
                @await Component.InvokeAsync("TopicBlock", new { systemName = "DeleteInformation" })
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <button type="button" name="delete" class="btn btn-primary btn-search" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-user-confirm" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
                    @T("Plugins.Tmotions.GDPR.User.DeleteMe")
                </button>

            </div>


        </div>

        <div id="delete-user-confirm" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="delete-user-title">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">@T("Plugins.Tmotions.GDPR.User.DeleteConfirmation")</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            @T("Plugins.Tmotions.GDPR.User.DeleteWarning")

                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" name="delete" class="btn btn-primary btn-search" data-toggle="modal" id="delete-confirm" data-target="delete-user-done" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
                                @T("Plugins.Tmotions.GDPR.User.DeleteYes")
                            </button>

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-search" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true"> @T("Plugins.Tmotions.GDPR.User.DeleteNo")</span></button>


                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div id="delete-user-done" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="delete-user-done-title">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    @*<div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close delete-ok"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                </div>*@

                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p class="delete-user-notification"></p>
                            <p>&nbsp;</p>
                            <p> @T("Plugins.Tmotions.GDPR.User.DeleteUserNotification2")</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Logout")" class="ico-logout btn btn-primary btn-search" data-controls-modal="delete-user-done" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"> @T("Plugins.Tmotions.GDPR.User.Ok")</a>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>





    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine. Your second modal doesn't close when clicked outside. Check the snippet. All you are missing is the `#` on your `data-target` attribute on your `button`.

```
<button type="button" name="delete" class="btn btn-primary btn-search" data-toggle="modal" id="delete-confirm" data-target="#delete-user-done" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
     @T("Plugins.Tmotions.GDPR.User.DeleteYes")
</button>
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="page account-page customer-info-page customer-delete-info">

    <div class="page-body">

        <div class="form-fields">
            <input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.CustomerId" id="customerId" />
            <div class="del-section">
                @await Component.InvokeAsync("TopicBlock", new { systemName = "DeleteInformation" })
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <button type="button" name="delete" class="btn btn-primary btn-search" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-user-confirm" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
                    @T("Plugins.Tmotions.GDPR.User.DeleteMe")
                </button>

            </div>


        </div>

        <div id="delete-user-confirm" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="delete-user-title">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">@T("Plugins.Tmotions.GDPR.User.DeleteConfirmation")</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            @T("Plugins.Tmotions.GDPR.User.DeleteWarning")

                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" name="delete" class="btn btn-primary btn-search" data-toggle="modal" id="delete-confirm" data-target="#delete-user-done" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
                                @T("Plugins.Tmotions.GDPR.User.DeleteYes")
                            </button>

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-search" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true"> @T("Plugins.Tmotions.GDPR.User.DeleteNo")</span></button>


                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div id="delete-user-done" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="delete-user-done-title">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    @*<div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close delete-ok"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                </div>*@

                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p class="delete-user-notification"></p>
                            <p>&nbsp;</p>
                            <p> @T("Plugins.Tmotions.GDPR.User.DeleteUserNotification2")</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Logout")" class="ico-logout btn btn-primary btn-search" data-controls-modal="delete-user-done" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"> @T("Plugins.Tmotions.GDPR.User.Ok")</a>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>





    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ahhhhh... silliest mistake :) thanks a lot.. you save my time

Comment: Glad to help :)